Excessive RAM Consumption by Wazuh-Indexer Process on Proxmox VE Agent
I've been utilizing Wazuh for several months now, with my own Wazuh server set up. I've added my Proxmox VE as an agent with the Wazuh agent, but I'm encountering some issues with it. Specifically, I'm facing problems with the Wazuh-indexer component running on the Proxmox VE. As far as I understand, Wazuh-indexer is a server component that works in conjunction with Wazuh-server and Wazuh-dashboard.
Interestingly, I have another Proxmox VE node where the same Wazuh-agent is installed, but it doesn't exhibit this problem. The main issue I'm facing is excessive RAM consumption by the Wazuh-indexer process, which seems to be increasing day by day. Initially, it was consuming around 2.5 GB of RAM, but now it's exceeding 2.76 GB.
I attempted to terminate the process using the SIGTERM kill command, but it restarted afterward. Unfortunately, I'm unsure about the service responsible for this process, making it challenging to disable it. Additionally, I'm not entirely clear on its purpose within the agent. Below is a screenshot displaying the details.

Can anyone explain what is the use of the process and how can I disable it?
